# Can I only use F3 to jump to definition in PyDev?

Tags: pydev

F3 key is good, but can I also just right click the function or object and select "open definition" to reach the definition, without using F3? This is what I can do in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can let ctrl pressed and click the word you select instead of using F3 if you like it better.